# How to hide all checkboxes using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I hide all checkboxes at once using CSS?

As of now I have the following:

```
#checkbox
{
  display:none
}
```

But this isn't working / being applied.

Comment: You need to specify appropriate selector to refer any element from your html. This can be done either by specifying id, class or just name of the tag. using id is bad idea in this case as it needs to be unique for all the elements. You can use classes also but as you want to hide all the elements on the page just use input[type='checkbox']. (This is an attribute selector as input can be any of text, radio, checkox etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by using a selector, by element and type:

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: IE 6 and earlier don’t support this selector, but all other browsers do.

Comment: Heh! Gather round, kids, for Hallowe’en is drawing in, and hear a tale to chill your very bones.

Answer (score 2):

It works,test is the class name for div.

```
.test input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .checkboxs{
        display:none;
        }
        </style>
    <form>
  <input class="checkboxs" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
  <input class="checkboxs" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> I have a car 
    </form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Those are radio buttons not checkboxes and you're hiding a div.

Comment: Yup Sorry ;( an error. But you can use a div to hide checkbox :)